The machine learning of identifying the inner workings of a lift
There are a few lifts that go up and down vertically. This system has its own inner workings so that it decides which lift to use at a specific level according to which lifts are being operated and whether or not they are going up and down.  Suppose we have data of which lifts are triggered to make their way to the level where a button is pressed. How can we use machine learning to learn this inner workings of this lift system?  For example whether it makes a lift that is already going down to keep going down or whether it always calls the nearest lift to reach out to the level when a button is pressed etc. What kind of machine learning is this?

It sounds like it could be a classification task, where your inputs/features include the triggered lifts, and the task is to predict which lift is called. Since only one lift can be called out of all the lifts, it's multi-class in particular.

Thank you but I don't get why this is a classification task.  If this is put in a neural network framework, what kind of network could this be?

My reading of it was that multiple lifts get called, but only one lift will get used. Is that right? That could be seen as a classification task of "which lift arrived out of all that were called".

Okay, thank you so much. Is there any online similar examples I can look up for?

I think an exploratory analysis of the data might be able to answer some of the questions about the workings of the system. If you have a record of lift behaviour (e.g. whether it is moving at the time of a button press, how close it is to the requested floor), then plotting the data can help reveal trends.
